# Как использовать результат выражения из условия в ветке самого условия?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, python-3.7

Вопрос по архитектуре кода. Допустим, есть множество `elif`'ов. В "верхних" условиях результат выражения **не** используется внутри ветки. Среди нижних есть условие, где результат выражения из `if`'а используется внутри ветки.

---

### Вопрос:

Как написать код так, чтобы этот результат не высчитывался дважды (при проверке и внутри ветки) и не высчитывался лишний раз (если, например, первое условие пройдёт)?

---

Примерный код:

```py
def task(val):
    if val % 2:
        print("cond1")  # результат выражения не используется
    elif val % 3:
        print("cond2")
    elif val % 5:
        print(val % 5)  # Тут результат из if'а используется внутри ветки
                        # и высчитывается второй раз. Этого хотелось бы избежать
    else:
        print("else")


task(6)
```

---

Знаю, что в Python 3.8 появился моржовый оператор, который решил бы мою проблему, но в системе используется Python 3.7, необходимо решение под него.

Comment: Без моржового оператора или костылей - никак. Если у вас в вашем реальном коде используется взятие остатка - то оставьте двойное вычисление, взятие остатка это достаточно лёгкая операция и экономить на ней нет смысла. Если в реальном коде нужно использовать какую-то тяжёлую операцию - то можно вынести её в отдельную функцию/класс и прикрутить к ней кэширование результата.

Comment: @Xander Нет. Взятие остатка просто для примера. В реальном коде вычисления намного сложнее. С кешированием идея хорошая, подумаю над этим...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь стандартной [functools.lru_cache()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) для кеширования результатов вызова функции:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=2**14)
def my_long_running_func(arg1):
    return arg1 % 5

def task(val):
    if val % 2:
        print("cond1")  # результат выражения не используется
    elif val % 3:
        print("cond2")
    elif my_long_running_func(val):
        print(my_long_running_func(val))  # Используется кешированный результат функциии
    else:
        print("else")
```

Comment: Очень сбивает с толку `% 5` в Вашем примере. Это вычисление же должно быть внутри декорируемой функции?

Comment: Ещё в документации сказано, что `maxsize`, равный степени двойки, даст больший прирост производительности :)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, вы черезчур упростили пример кода в функции, поэтому я не совсем понимаю что именно должно кешироваться... В любом случае принципиально решение не поменяется

Comment: Кешироваться должно было `val % 5`, я поправил Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @Xander за подсказку с кешированием. Реализовал класс-хранилище:

```py
class Cache:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.cached = value

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):  # Вызывает func(*args, **kwargs) с 
                                                # кешированием результата
        self.cached = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.cached


cache = Cache()


def task(val):
    if val % 2:
        print("cond1")  # результат выражения не используется
    elif val % 3:
        print("cond2")
    elif cache(lambda x: x % 5, val):
        print(cache.cached)  # Используется кешированный результат функциии
    else:
        print("else")


task(6)
```

Выглядит очень костыльно, буду рад лучшим решениям.